# How to check whether a string contains a substring which is present in a predefined array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, string-matching

What is the most efficient way to find out if a JavaScript array contains substring of a given string?

For example in case I have a JavaScript array

```
var a = ["John","Jerry","Ted"];
```

I need the condition which returns `true` when I compare the above array against the string:

```
"John Elton"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: read about `Array.indexOf()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ES6:

```
var array = ["John","Jerry","Ted"];
var strToMatch = "John Elton"
array.some(el => strToMatch.includes(el))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.some()` and `.includes()` methods:

```js
let arr = ["John","Jerry","Ted"];
let str = "John Elton";

let checker = (arr, str) => arr.some(s => str.includes(s));

console.log(checker(arr, str));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot use ES6:

```js
let arr = ["John","Jerry","Ted"];
let str = "John Elton";

var match = arr.some(function (name) {
  return str.indexOf(name) > -1;
});

console.log(match);
```